# Tag skin is ambiguous

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

[skin](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skin) is ambiguous it is used in the context of animal skin and vegetable peels.

There are currently 9 questions tagged with it. I suggest retagging those questions about fruit or vegetables and introduce [peel](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peel) for those.

I am aware that [peeling](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peeling) exists, but I don't think it covers all questions that [peel](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peel) would. Eg those about preparing or using the peel of a fruit.

Answer (score 2):

I started to implement your suggestion, but had to stop in the middle of doing it.

What tripped me up was this question. 
[Pickling green peaches: is the fuzz a must?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/33729/pickling-green-peaches-is-the-fuzz-a-must)

I recognize your good intentions, but English turns out to be more complicated than that. Nobody says "peach peel". People won't search for that. If I write into the tag wiki for skin to only ever use it for animal skin (and smartasses will start asking about fish, etc), they will still use the skin tag for peaches, because this is what you call the skin of a peach.

I tried to find a different word, but it seems that there is no word in English which distinguishes between the skin of a culinary animal and the skin of a culinary fruit/vegetable.

So I am leaving the [skin] tag in the questions for fruit and vegetables. The [peel](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peel) tag is already created, so I suggested it to be a synonym for [skin](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skin).

Finally, I don't think that this situation does much damage. I asked the mods of the larger sites, and they reminded me that they are full of tags which need a second tag for clarification, such as [regex](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regex) which will always contain questions the searching user isn't interested in, and has to be paired with [java](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java), [python](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) or some other programming language name to allow a focused search.

Sorry, I would have been glad to do as you asked, but once more it turns out that reality is more complex than we had planned for.

Comment: I didn't expect it to be this hard either. While using skin sounded natural in the context of [the question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/38236/8717) that triggered my meta question, I somehow felt it to be wrong in a 'professional' context.

Comment: @Baarn no problem. Besides, I just checked the book "The professional chef", it does use the word "skin" for squashes.

Comment: Yup, sometimes tags are a little ambiguous, it's okay. It's easy to get caught up in coming up with the exact right word for everything, but in the end, they're just about generally categorizing and searching questions, so they're most useful if they represent decent-sized categories with intuitive names.

Comment: I read the question and my first response was to agree. However, rumtscho, I've got with agree with you. When you peel potatoes, you're left with potato skins.